# Get a substring from a string for a regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

I have a string of the following form:

```
data-translate='view-7631b26ea80b1b601c313b15cc4e2ab03faedf30'>Avatar data
```

It can be in different languages, but in any case I need to get a string which is between the characters ' '
That is, in the example above, I need to get the following string:

```
view-7631b26ea80b1b601c313b15cc4e2ab03faedf30
```

Can I do this using the method string.replace(regexp, str) ?

I've highlighted the desired line using the following regular expression:

```
/'\b(.*)\b'/gm
```

Now, using the method `string.replace` I need to delete everything except that...

Got any suggestions?

Comment: It looks a lot like you're trying to use a regular expression to successfully extract data from HTML. [That's usually doomed to fail](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/157247). 80% solutions are pretty easy, but the 20% will get you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `match` method.

```
var data = "data-translate='view-7631b26ea80b1b601c313b15cc4e2ab03faedf30'>Avatar data";
data = data.match(/'\b(.*)\b'/gm)
```

Comment: You can  also try this one:

Answer (score 0):

You have good solid anchor text in either side, so:

```
var match = /data-translate='([^']+)'/.exec(str);
var substr = match && match[1];
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var str = "data-translate='view-7631b26ea80b1b601c313b15cc4e2ab03faedf30'>Avatar data";
var match = /data-translate='([^']+)'/.exec(str);
var substr = match && match[1];
document.body.innerHTML =
  "<pre>Got: [" + substr + "]</pre>";
```

But again, as I said in a comment, [using a simple regular expression to extract information from HTML is usually doomed to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/157247). For instance, you probably don't want to match this:

```
<p>The string is data-translate='view-7631b26ea80b1b601c313b15cc4e2ab03faedf30'</p>
```

...and yet, a simple regex solution will do exactly that. To properly handle HTML, you must use a proper HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one:

```
/\'([^\']+)\'/gm
```